# How to debug windows phone apps on windows tablet

Tags: windows-phone-8.1

Ok so I got windows 8.1 nextbook to test on. I created some basic browser app in visual studio running on virtual windows server 2012 r2. My main machine is windows 7. When I connect with USB cable nothing happens (who could have predicted that). I thought I could deploy my app on tablet and do a debug like that but haven't find a way to do it. Anybody here with experience in this scenario, I googled everywhere and the only thing I found is that documentation sucks

Comment: Can you please clarify: Are you writing a Windows phone app (to run on Windows Phone) out a Windows Store app (to run on Windows 8.1)? They are different. Tablets are not phones and they'll run different apps. If you write a universal app they'll be(mostly) source compatible but week build different packages.

Comment: Yup I wrote windows phone app. I though it is the same for phones and tablets (similar to android development)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot run a Windows Phone app on Windows. You need a Windows Phone or a Windows Phone emulator to run the Windows Phone app. To run on Windows you need to write a Windows Store app. Windows 8.1 on a tablet is the same as Windows 8.1 on a desktop or laptop computer.

In your case you'll probably need a physical Windows Phone since you are already running virtualized. The Windows Phone emulator is a Hyper-V image and is not supported nested in a Hyper-V guest OS.

If you write a Windows Universal app then the code will be mostly the same for the Windows and Windows Phone targets (the UI layer is usually different), so you can write and test the bulk of the app as a Windows Store app to run on your tablet and then recompile for Windows Phone.

Comment: Thank you. I developed for android before and didn't assume that this is different from WP. I will write my app as Windows Universal App and see how it runs on tablet